# How to replace Array.prototype.map.call including <img> tags

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, blogger

Im using below snippet in my blogger.

```
Array.prototype.map.call(document.getElementsByTagName("img"), img => img.src);
```

I get output of image src like :-

[image]

It work get my all image in my post. But Facing issue *s1600*

I need to change **s1600** to **s320** it by `array.prototype.map.call` or any other string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `replace()` method.

```
Array.prototype.map.call(document.getElementsByTagName("img"), 
    img => img.src.replace('/s1600/', '/s320/'));
```